# How best to implement rest/rpc for discord/telegram bots?

Tags: rest, architecture, bots, rpc

I have 3 servers:

- Website + api
- telegram bot
- discord bot

I want to implement rest/rpc architecture on servers with bots. More details: I make a request from the server to the server with the bot, it does something, I get a response.

If you do not use the libraries discord.js/pycord/aiogram and others, but directly discord/telegram api, this will greatly complicate development.

Over the course of a couple of weeks I came up with several solutions:

- modify bot libraries to suit my needs, but I’m losing support
- Use an event-based asynchronous model - event loop (like node.js),
- Launch several processes/threads (bot + mini server, to process my requests, implementing rest/rpc), here you will need to establish the exchange of information between them.

Which solution is better to achieve good performance in optimal development time?

Perhaps there are simpler/ready solutions to my problems. What would you do in this situation? Why?